# Generics itself Generics

Tags: java

I am not able to create Class with Generics. I want generic type parameter for the class, which itself accept generics as shown. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
public class Node<D, C<D,C>> {
    D data;
    C<D,C> children;

    public D getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(D data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public C<D,C> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(C<D,C> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, type parameters can't themselves have type parameters (although type arguments can). It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve here. If you could explain that, we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have Generics with two parameters like:

```
public class Node<T, X>
```

Then you can declare objects like:

```
Node<String, Node<String, String>> node;
```